# CSS When hover on a anchor, change the background color of the div it's on

Tags: html, css

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social {
  padding-left: 670px;
  /*margin-left: 670px;*/
  margin-top: -140px;
}
.blog_roll_links {
  margin-left: 58px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.blog_roll_links:hover {
  background-color: #C74451;
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
.social_links {
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bolgnsocial">
  <div class="blog">
    <h3 class="featArt">blogroll</h3>
    <div class="blog_roll_links">
      <a href="#" class="sociala" target="_blank">HTML5 Doctor</a>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_roll_links" style="margin-left:17em; margin-top: -40px;">
      <a href="#" class="sociala" target="_blank">HTML5 Spec (working draft)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_roll_links">
      <a href="#" class="sociala" target="_blank">Super Magazine</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="social">
    <h3 class="featArt">social</h3>
    <div class="social_links blog_roll_links">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"> facebook</a>
    </div>
    <hr align="right" style="border-style: outset; border-color: white; margin-left: 45px; width: 140px;" />

    <div class="social_links blog_roll_links">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"> twitter</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this little snip of code and two questions:

1. The "facebook" and "twitter" have the same class of "blog_roll_links", however, the final result is different. It supposed to change the div color when hovered over the link, like the links in blog does. I just cannot figure it out why "blog" and "social" have the same class, but don't have the same effect.
2. I want to change the text color to white when hovered over, i have the code in my CSS, why it won't work?

Comment: And if I change .social{padding-left: 670px;...} to  .social{margin-left: 670px;...} the blog part won't work as I want to(only change color when hovered over a link), strangest thing!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I highly recommend you to explore the browsers (chrome recommended) development tools.

if you inspect the elements you will see that in your current styling, that the anchor is nested inside your div AND that the anchor doesn't have the same width and height.

depending on which class you are adding :hover, css will react accordingly.

also the color of the font belongs to the anchor.

My suggestion is that you wrap the styling div inside the anchor, so that the whole div becomes a link ;)

Hope this helps you

Comment: Is there any way I can change the anchor's width and height? I tried to change it as <a style=" width.....>, it doesn't work....@Han Che

Comment: there are several ways, but none are good practice. 
1st. you define the div to have position:relative, then the anchor gets position:absolute, and height and width = 100%
2nd you simply give the anchor absolute values like width = 100px
Anyhow, the usually practice is to wrap the anchor around the content

Comment: Oh, I think I'll do the wrapping instead of changing width and height. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: you're welcome, I really recommend you to check out twitter bootstrap and some online tutorials on how to use them.
Then for learning effects, inspect their css and elements on chrome. Cheers